# PHP and SQLSRV - How to fix CharSet problems?

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding

My database uses `Latin1_General_CI_AI` for all texts it saves.

In PHP I use the default CharacterSet for `sqlsrv_connect()`. This is `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR` -> according to [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/sql-server-driver-php) post, it detects the charset. Now when I save data from php to my sql-server, it doesn't insert the correct chars. If I load data from my sql-server into my site, everything is correct. So I guess, `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR` is able to detect the charset on `SELECT` statements, but not on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements. Any idea to fix this?